# C# ini-parser issues

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, ini

I found that C# didn't directly support ini files, so I went on the prowl and found the following library called [ini-parser](https://github.com/rickyah/ini-parser). The usage shows an extremely simple example, but for some reason I can't get Visual studio 2010 to like it. If I copy the following exactly from the wiki on their web page:

```
        IniParser.FileIniDataParser parser = new FileIniDataParser();
    IniData parsedData = parser.LoadFile("TestIniFile.ini");
```

I get the following error, with the `parser` part of `parser.LoadFile()` underlined and the following error:

> Error 1   A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field,
>   method, or property
>   'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.parser'   C:\Users\Support\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs  28  30  WindowsFormsApplication1

I'm not sure what to make of what it's saying, or how to fix it. Can someone else offer up a suggestion/solution?

Comment: First, thanks for using my library! You might want to check out the latest version of the library located at github https://github.com/rickyah/ini-parser Example docs were also updated as the ones in Google Code are terribly outdated: https://github.com/rickyah/ini-parser/wiki/First-Steps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to do this in a field initializer. You're not allowed to refer to `this` within an instance field initalizer. Do it in the constructor instead:

```
private readonly IniData configuration;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    IniParser.FileIniDataParser parser = new FileIniDataParser();
    configuration = parser.LoadFile("TestIniFile.ini");
}
```

Or just do it inline without a separate variable for the parser at all:

```
private readonly IniData configuration =
    new FileIniDataParser().LoadFile("TestIniFile.ini");
```

(I'm assuming you don't actually need the parser for anything else, so it's pointless using a field for it.)

Comment: I made the opposite assumption - figuring the OP might want to save changes ;)

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful. Still fairly new with C#, so this would have never really occured to me. Now that I see it though, it makes sense. The program actually doesn't/won't make changes to the configuration file(at least, not planning on it), so this works great.

Comment: @Eric: Even if you *did* make changes to it, you could easily create a new parser later. Unless it's logically part of the *state* of the class, you shouldn't have an instance variable for it IMO. Also note that I've just changed the `configuration` variable to be read-only, which is generally a good idea if you don't actually want to be able to change it.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks, I hadn't noticed that earlier.

Answer (score 3):

The error message is basically saying that you can't use `parser` (another field) within a field initializer of the class (the initializer for `parsedData`).

You have to put this logic in the constructor:

```
FileIniDataParser parser = new FileIniDataParser();
IniData parsedData;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    parsedData = parser.LoadFile("TestIniFile.ini");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful and makes sense. I wasn't planning on making changes to the information later, but I definitely see why I'd use this over Jon's answer. Wish I could accept both answers.